# CSS top-navigation bar, template not working compass and sass

Tags: python, css, django, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to understand why the following does not work. I am trying to have a navigation bar on the top but I am using compass and scss files but this is basic CSS that I am just not understanding. I copy and pasted from sass-lang.com and only changed the name

the following is my scss file

```
#top-navigation {
  width: 80%;
  height: 23px;

  ul { list-style-type: none; }
  li {
    float: left;
    a { font-weight: bold; }
  }
}
```

and the following is my base.html

```
{% extends "skeleton.html" %}
{% load zinnia_tags i18n %}
{% load url from future %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}User test{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>       
        {% block header %}
    <div class ="container">
    <div id="header">
<ul class="top-navigation">
              <li>  
                    <a href="{% url "home" %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a>  
             </li>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li> {% trans "Logged in" %}: {{ user.username }} </li>
                {% endif %}

          <li>
            <a href="/blog/feeds/" title="RSS Feed of latest entries" class="feeds">
              RSS Feed
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>


    <hr />

        {% endblock %}



        {% block sidebar %}
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}



    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        {% block footer %}
        <hr />
        <p>this is the footer</p>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n zinnia_tags %}
{% load url from future %}
{% block title %}IVLoop.com{% endblock %}

</div>
    {% block content %}

        <h1>IVLoop.com</h1>
        <h2>Isla Vista Survival Handbook</h2>
        <h3>Phone Numbers and Links to all the stuff u need. Like food, fixing broken windows, 
        door locks and pluming. IVLoop.com is your IV survival guide</h3>

<p>IV loop is the term to describe the biz and res area around the loop in iv 
“did the Loop” generally means that you had a pitcher at the fine establishments located around the Isla Vista Loop.
 Start at Javan’s on Embarcadero Del Norte
then across to IVBC now remodeled as Embarcadero Hall, once the building was on fire… find out more and submit us your findings to be posted thanks
then down and around the loop for a beer at Super Cuca’s however they are moving next to Woodstock’s
up on Del Mar to Déjà Vu 
next is Giovanni’s 
across they way to El Sitio’s
Sam’s To Go 
Study Hall 
then over to Dublin’s
then Chino’s 
On the Side and Woodstock’s to finish of next to Javan’s
Please drink Responsibly! 

Is it isla as in island or is it isla as in is and why? </p>

{% endblock %}

</div>
```

the results i get is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>IVLoop.com</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public" />
    <meta name="robots" content="follow, all" />
    <meta name="language" content="en-us" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
    <meta name="description" content="Browse through a few featured Isla Vista Restaurants and we are here to take your order. 
Call night or day (805)689-6969 or order online" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="delivery,food,take-out " />
    <meta name="author" content="Brian Scott Carpenter" />

    <link rel="pingback" href="/xmlrpc/" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="home" href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="/static/css/screen.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/static/css/print.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="/static/zinnia/css/ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->


  </head>
  <body class="skeleton ">
    <div class="container">

    <div class ="container">
<ul class="top-navigation">
              <li>  
                    <a href="/">Home</a>  
             </li>


          <li>
            <a href="/blog/feeds/" title="RSS Feed of latest entries" class="feeds">
              RSS Feed
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>



    <hr />



        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>



        <h1>IVLoop.com</h1>
        <h2>Isla Vista Survival Handbook</h2>
        <h3>Phone Numbers and Links to all the stuff u need. Like food, fixing broken windows, 
        door locks and pluming. IVLoop.com is your IV survival guide</h3>

<p>IV loop is the term to describe the biz and res area around the loop in iv 
“did the Loop” generally means that you had a pitcher at the fine establishments located around the Isla Vista Loop.
 Start at Javan’s on Embarcadero Del Norte
then across to IVBC now remodeled as Embarcadero Hall, once the building was on fire… find out more and submit us your findings to be posted thanks
then down and around the loop for a beer at Super Cuca’s however they are moving next to Woodstock’s
up on Del Mar to Déjà Vu 
next is Giovanni’s 
across they way to El Sitio’s
Sam’s To Go 
Study Hall 
then over to Dublin’s
then Chino’s 
On the Side and Woodstock’s to finish of next to Javan’s
Please drink Responsibly! 

Is it isla as in island or is it isla as in is and why? </p>



        <hr />
        <p>this is the footer</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

I know that compass is working because when I work with other class's it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in base.html

```
<div id ="top-navigation">

then <ul>
```

they where combined